# ATI OpenCL SDK on OSX

Tags: macos, sdk, opencl, ati

I am owning new MPB with ATI-GK. I'am curios, whether i can download the sdk, special the example collection and profiler, for OSX or I have to run Windows/Linux nativelly, because i have found only versions for windows and linux?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: same issue here - have you found an answer to this?

Comment: Yes and no. There is no SDK for Mac, but: you have more or less support in Xcode for *.cl files. Or you can install VM Fusion with Windos and run opencl for CPU, where you debug and design code, which you can run on graphic card later.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have Mac OSX 10.6 or above (which you do if you have a new Macbook Pro), you already have OpenCL installed, under something like /Developer/GPU Computing/OpenCL.

Comment: I can compile OpenCL programs, but i cannot find the installed SDK. Yes, i am using 10.6.x