# Mac OSX 10.10 AMD APP SDK Location

Tags: macos, opencl, caffe, amd-gpu

I have spent the past hour looking for the AMD APP SDK location for Mac OSX 10.10 and cannot find it for the life of me. I don't know the file name even so I can't just search for it and searching SDK doesn't work.

I know I have it because I'm on a Mac Pro with AMD cards.

I'm trying to set up an OpenCL version of Caffe and need a reference to my SDK for it to compile (https://github.com/amd/OpenCL-caffe/wiki). Because I'm not able to set the `export AMDAPPSDKROOT=/opt/AMDAPPSDK-*/` I'm getting a compile error `File /Users/mbahr/Downloads/OpenCL-caffe-stable/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c: /* */`

I've looked in my usr and found nothing. I looked for this comment [on where the openCL SDK would be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5795305/5500368) and found nothing there, I don't even have a Developer folder as far as I can tell... much less a GPU Computing folder.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I have it because I'm on a Mac Pro with AMD cards.

If you are running OS X, you neither have nor need the AMD APP SDK.

I've just built `OpenCL-Caffe` from the GitHub repository on my own MacBook (10.11). The only configuration options I had to pass to CMake were to tell it where `clBLAS` was installed.

The only changes I needed to make to the source code were to replace `#include <CL/...>` with `#include <OpenCL/...>` in these files:

```
include/caffe/common.hpp
include/caffe/util/math_functions.hpp
```

and to remove `#include <malloc.h>` from `src/caffe/device.cpp`.

Comment: "If you are running OS X, you neither have nor need the AMD APP SDK."

Really? Good to know. I'll start tweaking the files and see if I can get it to compile then get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Yep! Thanks, that helped a lot. I'm getting other libraries configured instead as I've figured out that I was having issues with protobuf not actually installing correctly.